# How can I overlay UK district boundaries on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

An example of what I'm looking to do is on http://yourtaximeter.com/main/home#/main/home .  If you search for Manchester to Leeds, you'll see that it highlights in pink the district area covered by Manchester.

When you select Salford as the from address, it will highlight Salford district.  I'm not really too sure where to start.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a ressource where you can get the boundaries for that area and create a polygon based on it.

In this special case these data are returned by an request via AJAX to http://yourtaximeter.com/api/, when you inspect the response you'll see that the `district.enc`-property of the returned object contains an encoded polyline which defines the outline for the highlighted area.

Comment: Thanks, on their api documentation page (http://yourtaximeter.com/main/api#/main/api/documentation-v2/taxi-fare-calculator-v2/response), they describe this property as: "A google maps encoding of the district polygon".  Is there a way that I can calculate this encoding myself?

Comment: you may encode a Polyline(path) or decode an encoded Polyline(path) by using the [encoding-methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#encoding), but the Maps-API doesn't provide the data for the districts somewhere else(e.g. the data provided by yourtaximeter.com when it's allowed to use them )

Comment: don't suppose you know where I can get this polygon line data?  I can't seem to find a decent API for it anywhere

Comment: Here is a FusionTable which seems to be fine: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=16RlvT0U2gcuENoydpohUSel2BEqmbpYfyfrMNWk